# Show a gif animation

Tags: java, android, gif

Ok so first let me say that I searched everywhere in the internet, even here, and I can't find the answer, so I have no code to show.
I am just trying to make a gif animation in an app playing all the time, how can I do it, SurfaceView, Movie, what? Please explain me with sample code

P.S. As I said I searched EVERYWHERE! So PLEASE, if you are going to send me warnings or stuff, just delete my thread.....

Answer (score 0):

I did it, instead of 
animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
it should've been
animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();

the weird thing is that in the Android documentation in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html
the example was with getBackground...... anyone knows why?